# How can I add new Class in Magento2 sales grid?

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2, order-grid

I was trying to add new class in Sales order grid in table rows based on some conditions in admin of Magento2 but I couldn't succeed.

Can anyone help me out how to do such thing?

please find attached screen shot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172743/magento-2-add-css-to-order-grid-on-basis-of-custom-column

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have override Magento backend theme and called my custom backend theme and added js with custom module to add new class.

Comment: @Teja , why you down vote my answer?

Comment: Bhargav, Please help me with the same.  Please share more info how did you resolve it?